# Can I say "yeah" to mean "keep going"?

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language

If someone(like a professor) is correcting me or teaching me something I don't know, and there is a pause, can I say "yeah" to mean "yes, I understand, please keep going?". Because it's a really small pause and the explanation wasn't over yet, I don't think I should say "I understand." and I think "keep going" would be kind of rude.

Comment: “Okay.” (Nod.) “I'm with you so far.”

Comment: ''Keep going'' would be very rude.  I agree that ''with you so far'' is a nice one as indicates that you are following to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start to analyse language there are all sorts of grunts and noises that people make to show that they are listening.  And there is lots of body and face language too.

So you will hear sounds that are something like "uh-huh" or "mmn" and you will see eyebrow flashes and nods.

Babies will start to engage in this kind of conversation before they learn to speak, taking turns and alternately listening and vocalising.

Of course you can say "yeah", but *how* you say "yeah" is the thing.  You can also use "yeah" as a way of interrupting, or at least indicating that you have something to add.

But the real message here is that you need to relax.  You can say "yeah" or "I see" or "right" or "I understand", or "uh-huh" or nod, or probably lots more besides.